# Value updates after 1 second

Tags: react-admin

A value in a ChipField keeps disappearing after 1 second, after first render.

```
<ArrayField source="kpi">
  <SingleFieldList>
    <TextField source="title" reference="kpi.title" />
  </SingleFieldList>
</ArrayField>
```

This is the data

```
"kpi": [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Test",
    "goal": "1000",
    "currentvalue": "2",
    "startvalue": "1",
    "importance": 99
  }
],
```

We are able to get the id to stay but we cant make it work with any of the other data.
If we only write `kpi` instead of `kpi.title`, it shows the id.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use only

`<TextField source="title" />`

There is no need for `reference`.

Also, try `ChipField`, see [docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#array-fields)